# Change fragment dimensions when selected in viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, layoutparams

Is there a way to increase the size of the current fragment and then reducing it back when its not selected in a ViewPager?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `ViewPager.PageTransformer`.

With a `PageTransformer`, you can zoom the View as it is being swiped into view.

Here's an example of one that will zoom the way you want.  Try this to start:

```
    public static class PageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(View page, float position) {

            // this part changes the scale, which is the zoom part
            page.setScaleX(1.0F - .33F * Math.abs(position));
            page.setScaleY(1.0F - .33F * Math.abs(position));

            // this part sets up so the page zooms from the center
            page.setPivotX(page.getWidth() / 2.0F);
            page.setPivotY(page.getHeight() / 2.0F);
        }
    }
```

To set it up:

```
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new PageTransformer());
```

[Customize the Animation with PageTransformer | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer)

Comment: what if i don't want the Fragment to cover the entire width of screen? In that case the left and right fragments will also be visible and will have the same size!

Comment: Are you using a `FragmentPagerAdapter` where `getPageWidth()` doesn't return 1.0?  I can't tell by your diagram where the boundaries of your fragment are.  Notwithstanding, the `PagerTransformer` can change the size of the left and right fragments as well, even if your fragment doesn't cover the entire width of the screen.